# Overload for ostream on vectors throws error when using std::copy

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading, c++14

I am wondering why the following fails to compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename...> class Container, class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const Container<T>& c) {
    oss << "[";
    std::copy(std::cbegin(c), std::prev(std::cend(c)), std::ostream_iterator<T>(oss, ","));
    return oss << (*std::crbegin(c)) << "]";
}

auto main() -> int {
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> data(5);
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/431617423f92ba4e

It compiles fine when I do **one** of the following:

- Remove the line with `std::copy`
- Change the vector to be a one-dimensional vector (`std::vector<unsigned> data(5)` for example).

What is it about `std::copy` that is causing the error?

---

Debugging with clion, this is the type of the nested vector that gets printed in the `crbegin` line:

[image]

Comment: Also it seems like you're trying to call `<<` on a `std::vector<unsigned>`, and that overload does not exist.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, if I remove the `std::copy` line, it compiles fine

Comment: `template <typename...> class Container` line right here, can only take one container inside it, you have two inside each other `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>>`!

Comment: @smac89 Because the container cannot copy a `std::vector<unsigned>` from `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>>` inside the ostream...

Comment: @Ruks, I don't think that's what the problem is. The overload definitely matches the nested vector. Problem is when it tries to use `std::copy` to print the contents

Comment: @Ruks, can you explain what you mean by "moving". Why can't an lvalue be moved?

Comment: @smac89 Have you tried checking what type it gives you when you dereference the iterator... `typeid(std::cbegin(c)).name()`?

Comment: @Ruks, see my edit

Comment: Try to put space in between std::vector<std::vector<unsigned`>>` it should be like this std::vector<std::vector<unsigned> >

Comment: @smac89 -- The answer given by xskxzr basically mimics my initial comment.  I compiled your code with Visual Studio, and it pinpointed the issue with `operator <<`.  Note it is *not* the `operator <<` you were referring to -- it is the `operator <<` that `ostream_iterator` uses.

Comment: @McBern that extra space between `>>` is not needed from C++11 onwards. The code is using language features not present in pre C++11, so this is not an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `operator<<` is not visible to `std` entities.

Note `std::ostream_iterator<T>` outputs values [as if through `operator<<`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ostream.iterator.ops#1), and according to [[temp.dep.res]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.res#1):

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are
>   considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point])
>     and from the definition context.

... your `operator<<` is neither visible at the point of definition of `std::ostream_iterator<T>`, nor in the namespace `std`, so the `operator<<` used in `std::ostream_iterator<T>` cannot be correctly resolved.

Comment: Seems so.  When the code is compiled in Visual Studio 2017, the error points exactly to `std::ostream_iterator` and the failure to resolve `operator <<` for `std::vector<unsigned>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<<` is not visible to `std::ostream_iterator`, so it can't call your `operator<<` on elements of the input container. Just use a manual loop instead, then it will work as expected.

Also, `std::prev(std::cend(c))` and `*(c.crbegin())` are **undefined** when the container is empty, so watch out for that.

Also, `std::vector` (like most other standard containers) has more than 1 template parameter, so use `typename... Ts` instead of `class T` in your operator's template parameters.

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template < template<typename...> class Container, typename... Ts>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const Container<Ts...>& c) {
    oss << "[";
    if (!c.empty()) { // use std::empty() in C++17 and later
        auto last = std::prev(std::cend(c));
        /*
        using value_type = typename Container<Ts...>::value_type;
        std::copy(std::cbegin(c), last, std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(oss, ","));
        */
        for(auto iter = std::cbegin(c); iter != last; ++iter) 
            oss << *iter << ",";
        oss << *last;
    }
    return oss << "]";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> data(5);
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
[[],[],[],[],[]]
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/YYHVpH)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an experiment that will lead you toward the answer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace std {
template <template <typename...> class Container, class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const Container<T>& c) {
    oss << "[";
    std::copy(std::cbegin(c), std::prev(std::cend(c)), std::ostream_iterator<T>(oss, ","));
    return oss << (*std::crbegin(c)) << "]";
}
}

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> t{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> data(5, t);
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sidenote: without defining `t`, it'll compile (i.e., your `operator<<` will be found when needed), but if you try to run it, it'll crash--trying to use `std::prev(std::cend(c))` on an empty container isn't going to end well.

Of course, this does violate the requirements of the standard (defining your `operator<<` inside namespace std like this isn't allowed), but at least with typical compilers, the name will now be found so the code will compile.